# How to set the padding of QTableView cells through CSS?

Tags: c++, css, qt

Is it possible to define the padding of QTableView cells? I would expect this to be possible using CSS stylesheets, but the documentation does not describe a method to do this.

The following stylesheet does not have the desired effect:

```
QTableView {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

as it influences the padding property of the widget as a whole, not of the individual cells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I've been struggling with this recently.

I found out that by setting

`tableView->verticalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);`

the padding set in your CSS will then be applied to the top and bottom of the cell, too!

Comment: Note that this answer is available for Qt 5.0, not for versions 4.x

Answer (score 18):

I managed to get it to work using the `::item` sub-control specifier as follows:

```
QTableView::item
{
  border: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Note that setting the border property here is necessary to get this to work. Also, this is not super ideal, since it only seems to influence the left and right padding of the `QTableView` cell. I can live with it for now though.

Comment: Does anyone know why the 'border: 0px;' is required to make this work?

Comment: The [Qt Style Sheet reference page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-reference.html) entry for QTableView notes:

`Warning: If you only set a background-color on a QTableCornerButton, the background may not appear unless you set the border property to some value. This is because, by default, the QTableCornerButton draws a native border which completely overlaps the background-color.` It's possible that the same sort of requirement applies here for the padding.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Every time I click on another cell the text is invisible because a white rectangle is drawn over it.

Comment: For me, the cell text also gets cleared on selection if I 0px the border.
But it seems to work fine with just the padding (using pyqt).