# How can I style the cells of a QTableWidget in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new to Qt and PyQt and wonder how to style the cells of a QTableWidget. For example, I want to add some etxra padding. I tried to set a stylesheet like in the code below, but it doesn't have any effect. I also searched the internet, but couldn't find a solution.

I use PyQT5 (python-pyqt5 5.15.4-1 on Arch Linux).

This is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Table Test')
        table = QTableWidget(self)
        table.setColumnCount(4)
        table.setRowCount(3)
        for j in range(table.rowCount()):
            for k in range(table.columnCount()):
                table.setItem(j, k, QTableWidgetItem("{}{}".format(j, k)))
        self._centralWidget = table
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self.resize(500, 200)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = MainWindow()
    view.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item {padding: 5px}")
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Many classes inherit from more "generic" classes: QTableWidget inherits from QTableView, and it's the "convenience" version of it (it provides its own private model). Googling "qtableview padding" gives this result as first: [How to set the padding of QTableView cells through CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1733857) (you need to set a null border). If you need more customization, you need to be more precise, as it depends on many aspects, not everything is customizable through stylesheets (since they just "implement" the CSS concepts and syntax, but don't provide all CSS capabilities.

Comment: @musicamante thank you very much, that was very helpful and enabled me to solve the problem! I'll summarize the solution in an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer the question myself. I found the solution with the help of the comment of @musicamante above.

Setting the margin to 0  did the trick:

```py
view.setStyleSheet("QTableWidget::item {border: 0px; padding: 5px;}")
```

Now the cells have a padding of 5px.